# Display .jpeg files from MySQL gathered with PHP form

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

Currently I am working on an html/php page that will display a random image and piece of text taken from a table with two VARCHAR(200) fields.

The issue is that the script will not display files with a .jpeg extension. However, it will display .png,.gif,.jpg extensions.

The images are being saved correctly in the /images folder. Accessing them directly through HTTP works perfectly fine. The echo command, however, won't display files with .jpg extensions.

This is the HTML/PHP code for the display page (excluding the connection to the MySQL database.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>MIXED MESSAGES</title>
</head>
 <?php 

 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "images/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $name=$_POST['name'];  
 $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 
<body>
<?php

  $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submissions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");

  while($rand = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){
    echo $rand['name'] . "<br>";
    echo "<img src=http://www.voiid.org/images/".$rand['pic'] ."> <br>";
  }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I feel the most efficient way to address the issue would be to find a way to rename all .jpeg files to .jpg.

The images are also stored on the server in the /images/ folder.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see specifically any reason jpeg wouldn't work.  Are the jpeg files being saved correctly in the images/ folder?  If so, what happens when you access them directly through HTTP?

Comment: They are being saved correctly in the /images folder. Accessing them directly through HTTP works perfectly fine. The echo command, however, won't display files with .jpg extensions.

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference but for URLs I really tend to wrap them in quotes: `echo "<img src='http://www.voiid.org/images/".$rand['pic'] ."'> <br>";`  After doing that, what does the HTML source show in your browser for that line?

Comment: Just to be sure, print out the URL of the jpg only, without it wrapped by the <img> tag to see if the output URL is the desired URL

Comment: @Devon WOW! That did it! If you upvote this question I can tick your answer and get you the rep you deserve. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad I could help.  It is standard for HTML to use quotes around attributes, but it usually works without it just fine.  Probably just the browser being picky.

Comment: Post this as an answer so I can give you the reputation!